# How to check a users role before they are routed to a web forms page with ASP.net 4.0 in VB.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

I have an asp.net web forms application that uses asp.net membership and URL Routing.
Because of the way Roles work, i cant put an "AND" or "OR", etc. in the allow/deny tags of the web.config file that resides in each folder.

This is a business website that that is being ported from a vb.net win forms project that contianed many apps. (The win forms project have a custom authentication system.)

The web app is structured in a way to mimic the desktop suites and a folder was created for each app.
There are also common folders where any user of any app can generate a report.

The roles are structured as such

App1
    Licensee

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: put that validation on your global.asax's Application_BeginRequest event.

If you want, you could create an HttpHandler for managing that. Here's more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5c67a8bd(v=vs.71).aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: I looked in MSDN and found documentation that tells you how to do it but it doesnt actually show you how to do it. http://chriscavanagh.wordpress.com/2008/03/11/aspnet-routing-goodbye-url-rewriting/ is the website i tried using but i could get the code to convert to vb correctly

Comment: Try yo put it first on the global asax, it's the simplest way. If the code gets ugly, put the logic in another class and just call it from the event handler in your global.asax. At least, give it a try to know if the solution works. If it does, then think of refactor it.

Comment: Wrong site before. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx is the site i tried using. i can check the users roles and redirect when needed, I just cant get the code to convert to vb correctly. when i convert if (page != null)
    {  var routablePage = page as IRoutablePage;
      if (routablePage != null)
        routablePage.RequestContext = requestContext;
    }
to vb i get a red squiggily errror under Iroutablepage. I thought aspx pages in .net 4 implemented iroutablepage. I even tried casting the ihttphandler(page) to an aspx page but that doesnt work either.